# Lancer steering vibration at high speed

Tags: mitsubishi, lancer

I have a Mitsubishi Lancer 2003 glxi petrol version. When I drive it at speed of 120 km/h the steering wheel vibrates, but below 100 it is fine. What could be the cause?

I recently replaced a wheel ball joint tie rod end and low arm. A person at the garage can't identify this issue, even alignment has been done but wheel balancing is pending  but garage guy informed me that the front suspension is weak and he suggested replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

A wheel isn't balanced. It's almost certainly that - the symptoms match perfectly.

Get that done, it's very cheap - and while it may be good to get suspension looked at in an older car, you should always start with the cheap and easy solutions.

Comment: If the balancing doesn't seem to fix the issue, it could be possible that the wheels are bent/deformed beyond what can be remedied with weights (the wheels will then need to be repaired if possible). This is something that they can look out for when balancing the wheels.